# does the authority of compressed NFTs work the same as normal NFTs?

Tags: nfts, authority

[image]

Does the traditional concept of having a freeze authority and mint authority the same for Compressed NFTs? Where there is a specific scope for each account found in the authorities array? If so,  are there example where there are more than one authority with different scope?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the traditional concept of having a freeze authority and mint authority is the same for Compressed NFTs on Solana. However, there is a specific scope for each account found in the authorities array.

The freeze authority can freeze the token, preventing it from being transferred or updated. The mint authority can mint new tokens, but only up to the maximum supply specified when the token was created.

Here is an example of a Compressed NFT with multiple authorities:

```
{
  "name": "My Compressed NFT",
  "symbol": "MCNFT",
  "description": "This is my Compressed NFT.",
  "image": "https://example.com/my-compressed-nft.png",
  "properties": {
    "type": "Image",
    "creator": "John Doe"
  },
  "authorities": [
    {
      "type": "FreezeAuthority",
      "address": "0x1234567890abcdef1234567890abcdef12345678"
    },
    {
      "type": "MintAuthority",
      "address": "0x9876543210fedcba9876543210fedcba98765432"
    }
  ]
}
```

In this example, the freeze authority is allowed to freeze the token, but is not allowed to mint new tokens. The mint authority is allowed to mint new tokens, but is not allowed to freeze the token.